# Is it possible to take an App off the playstore, but restore it later?

Tags: android

If I published an app, but take it off the playstore later, can I republish it? What if I upload another version of the app instead, can I republish the old APK that I took off earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can republish the app, and yes you can republish the old APK because you the option:

Console Play Store https://play.google.com/apps/publish

Select your app

Deploy Administration

App Version

And you found the option, and the history of your APK's

[History of APK's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB86T.png)

And yes, Console save all the information, date that was uploaded, apks, version code, etc

[Detail of version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3BaZ.png)

Comment: does it save dated version history
ie. v2.0 was released on X date
or no version history once unpublished?